# PHP sort certain numbers from an array

Tags: php

trying to solve a kata here where the instructions are:

You will be given an array of numbers. You have to sort the odd numbers in ascending order while leaving the even numbers at their original positions.

Examples

```
[7, 1]  =>  [1, 7]
[5, 8, 6, 3, 4]  =>  [3, 8, 6, 5, 4]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]  =>  [1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0]
```

I come up with this code

```
function sortArray(array $arr) : array {
  $oddNumbers = [0];
  $oddNumbersPlaced = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++)
    if ($arr[$i] % 2 != 0) {
      $oddNumbers[$oddNumbersPlaced] = $arr[$i];
      $arr[$i] = 'a';
      $oddNumbersPlaced =+ 1;
     };
    
  $oddNumbers = sort($oddNumbers);
  
  for ($n = 0; $n < count($arr); $n++){
    $oddPlaced = 0;
    if ($arr[$n] == 'a'){
      $arr[$n] = $oddNumbers[$oddPlaced];
      $oddPlaced = $oddPlaced+1;
    }
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

but get an error at line 17 :

```
$arr[$n] = $oddNumbers[$oddPlaced];
```

which says 'Trying to access array offset on value of type bool';

can someone explain to me how and where do i get a bool value plz ?

Answer (score 0):

Do not assign

```
sort($oddNumbers);
```

to

```
$oddNumbers
```

because sort always return true, it accepts pass by reference.

Example:

```
// Create an array of odd numbers
$oddNumbers = [7, 1, 5, 9, 3];

// Sort the array in ascending order using the sort() function
sort($oddNumbers);

// Print the sorted array
print_r($oddNumbers);
```

will result in

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 9
)
```

Comment: how can i sort oddNumbers without having a boolean after it then ? should i create a new function equal to $oddNumbers ?

Comment: You just don't have to assign it. The answer here is a bit confusing because you need to keep the sort() but not reassign it to $oddNumbers :)

Comment: Like I said, sort always return true, and accept passed by reference, so it will sort it. If you assigned it, what you are assigning is true, because sort return true

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```php
<?php
$array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]; // ...,2,9,0
$odds = [];
$even = [];

foreach ($array as $val) 
{
    if($val % 2 !== 0) 
    {
        $odds[] = $val;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $even[] = $val;
    }
}

sort($odds);
rsort($even);

$array = [];
foreach ($odds as $key => $val) 
{
    $array[] = $val;
    if(isset($even[$key])) 
    {
        $array[] = $even[$key];
    }
}

print_r($array);
// output:
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 6
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 4
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 0
)
```